# How to create new column based on other column's values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

**EDIT**

I tried this solution(below answer) to solve this problem.

```
select timestamp, id, coalesce(
        max(case when val = 1 then unix_timestamp(timestamp) end) over (partition by idorder by timestamp),
        min(unix_timestamp(timestamp)) over (partition by id)
    )) as global_e
from table
```

This solution works. But execution - fetching time are the 30 - 5 seconds in mysql.

Bu when I try this solution(same above but different version. or am i wrong?);

```
select timestamp, id, coalesce(
            max(case when val = 1 then unix_timestamp(timestamp) end) over prt,
            min(unix_timestamp(timestamp)) over prt        
       )) as global_e
from table 
window as prt (partition by id order by timestamp)
```

With above query, execution - fetching time are 5 - 30 seconds. Why??

---

I have a table `X` like this;

```
id       timestamp       x_val
1          ts1            0
1          ts2            0
1          ts3            1
1          ts4            0
1          ts5            1 
2 ...
...
```

As you can see `x_val` column value can only be `0 or 1`. But I want to create new column based on other columns. All values partitioned by `id`.

I want output table like this;

```
id       timestamp       x_val    global_e
1          ts1            0         1_ts1
1          ts2            0         1_ts1
1          ts3            1         1_ts3
1          ts4            0         1_ts3
1          ts5            1         1_ts5
2 ...
...
```

In above table, `global_e` is created based on `id and timestamp`. If `x_val` is 1, that means `global_e` must be equal to the `id + current row timestamp`. If it is 0, `global_e` must be equal to the previous value.

How can I create `global_e` column like above?

Comment: What is your MySQL version ? Do `SELECT version();` and report the result. Also, what have you tried so far ? Edit the question, to add your coding efforts, so that we can push you in the right direction. Hint: this is a [Window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) problem

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, you can use a cumulative max.  This is basically:

```
select x.*,
       max(case when x_val = 1 then timestamp end) over (partition by id order by timestamp) as global_e
from x;
```

This is not quite what you want, because you want the minimum, when there is no row with `1`.  So, use `coalesce()`:

```
select x.*,
       coalesce(max(case when x_val = 1 then timestamp end) over (partition by id order by timestamp),
                min(timestamp) over (partition by id)
               ) as global_e
from x;
```

In earlier versions, a correlated subquery is probably the simplest approach:

```
select x.*,
       (select coalesce(max(case when x2.x_val = 1 then timestamp end), min(timestamp)
        from x x2
        where x2.id = x.id and 
              x2.timestamp <= x.timestamp
       ) as global_e
from x;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Your answer worked! But I wonder how be query performance when we use `two partition by(one of them also have order by)` in the same select statement?

Comment: @mangrrua . . . Probably about half the speed of one partition by.  I'm not sure that is a significant consideration when trying to figure out the logic.

Comment: When I use the two partition by in the select statement, execution- fetching time are the 30 - 5 seconds in mysql. But when I use the partition by attribute after the `from` statement in the query(then I use this partition by statement in the two column), execution- fetching time is the 5 - 30 seconds. Why?

Comment: I've updated my question according to the my previous question.